# Is it possible for a two-way edit relationship in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We know spreadsheets always had one-way referencing.

One good thing for Google Sheets is that it is scriptable.

**Is it possible in Google Sheets to have a database-type two-way edit relationship on cells/ranges?**

---

Specific case:

I have a Sheet with raw data. I have another using the `FILTER` function to show the necessary "searched for" information. It is of course not directly possible to edit the output of `FILTER`. Could JavaScript/workaround be created to allow editing the outputted information and reflect the changes on the source Sheet?

This would be a great feature, a database-like ability in the simplicity of a spreadsheet GUI.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible, but what can I give you is some tutorials that I think can give you an idea on how to work Google Sheets in a Database. Try to check this [one](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/10/google-sheets-as-a-database-authenticated-insert-with-apps-script-using-execution-api/), It explains here how to work Google Sheets as a Database with the help of [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) and Execution API. It also gives sample code and screenshot for you to follow. You can also check this [blog](http://kovalent.co/blog/google-docs-as-a-backend/).

Comment: Thanks @KENdi. I'll check it out and let you know what I'm able to do with it. Good day!

Comment: You might want to look at: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/push

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

Yes, it's possible by using [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/).

## Explanation

I posted an [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90129/88163) that shows on way to do this on a similar question on Stack Exchange Web Applications site. The basic idea is to have a on edit event triggered function on each spreadsheet that sends the changes on the spreadsheet to the other spreadsheet.

IMPORTANT NOTE

The on edit event triggers work on a "best effort basis", meaning that sometimes the an edit will not fire the trigger.

## References

[Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)